# Confusion over ecsInstanceRole role for ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, identity-management

From reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html it mentions creating a role called `ecsInstanceRole` which can then be applied to the running containers. If it needs to be created i.e. it isn't a built in AWS role, does the name matter? Is there something important about the name that I'm missing or is this just a recommended naming convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is just following suggestive naming conventions, feel free to name it as you like.